# Pandas: Filling missing values, based on particular column, by adding some days

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data-frame `df` like this:

[Date: mm/dd/yyyy]

```
Date           Student_id    subject     Subject_Scores
11/30/2020     1000101       Math           70
NaN            1000101       Physics        75
NaN            1000101       Biology        60
11/25/2020     1000101       Chemistry      49
NaN            1000101       English        80
12/02/2020     1000101       Sociology      50
11/25/2020     1000102       Physics        80
NaN            1000102       Math           90
12/15/2020     1000102       Chemistry      63
NaN            1000103       English        71
```

Say, each exam has 3 days of the gap in between, How can I add **4 days** for each of the individual Student_id's and fill wherever `NaN` present? (Eg: 11/30/2020, if added with 4 days we get 12/04/2020, if added 4  days to that, we get 12/08/2020)

**P.S*:* If the date is already present in some column value, considering that we supposed to add 4 days and fill next NaN's for particular `Student_id`.

Output `date_df` must look something like this:

```
Date           Student_id    subject     Subject_Scores
11/30/2020     1000101       Math           70
12/04/2020     1000101       Physics        75
12/08/2020     1000101       Biology        60
11/25/2020     1000101       Chemistry      49
11/29/2020     1000101       English        80
12/02/2020     1000101       Sociology      50
11/25/2020     1000102       Physics        80
11/29/2020     1000102       Math           90
12/15/2020     1000102       Chemistry      63
NaN            1000103       English        71
```

```
Please do suggest any code ideas, Thanks for the help, in advance!
```

Comment: what about last student id having first date as NaN.. what you will do with that date ?

Comment: Since the last `Student_id` is having the first date as `NaN`, it's not possible to add days randomly for that Student. (if we try to fill using groupby, I guess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert column `date` to datetimes if necessary, then create groups by missing values per `Student_id` by [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) and create days for append in [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with multiple by `4` and converting to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), last use [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html) for forward filling missing values per groups and add timedeltas:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

g = df['Date'].notna().groupby(df['Student_id']).cumsum()
add = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby([g,'Student_id']).cumcount().mul(4), unit='D')

df['Date'] = df.groupby('Student_id')['Date'].ffill().add(add)
print (df)
        Date  Student_id    subject  Subject_Scores
0 2020-11-30     1000101       Math              70
1 2020-12-04     1000101    Physics              75
2 2020-12-08     1000101    Biology              60
3 2020-11-25     1000101  Chemistry              49
4 2020-11-29     1000101    English              80
5 2020-12-02     1000101  Sociology              50
6 2020-11-25     1000102    Physics              80
7 2020-11-29     1000102       Math              90
8 2020-12-15     1000102  Chemistry              63
9        NaT     1000103    English              71
```